# How can I combine echo and a script in the same line?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to learn how to make a script where it makes you look like you are hacking to trick some of my associates but I cannot find how to combine code with and echo command. As you can see I know almost nothing about batch but I am actively trying to learn, I have borrowed code inside of this script too.

```
    @echo off

echo.

echo.

color a

title Test

cls
set /a chance= %random% %%30+1
echo %chance%
IF %chance% GTR 10 (IF %chance% LSS 15 (
      - located %chance%
))

for /l %%x in (1, 1, 100000) do echo %%x -
```

Comment: You have not explained exactly what you want to happen, or what is actually happening, those are thae basic ingredients for getting assistance with something. BTW `- located 11`, `- located 12`, `- located 13`, or `- located 14` are not commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help you out any?

```sh
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
TITLE Test
COLOR A
CLS
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,1000000) DO (SET /A "CHANCE = (!RANDOM! %% 30) + 1"
    IF !CHANCE! GTR 10 IF !CHANCE! LSS 15 ECHO - located !CHANCE!)
PAUSE
```